# ¿Cómo mostrar muchos datos en una gráfica en R?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código para hacer una gráfica de barras.

```
y<-(dtab$clave_estado)
x<-(dtab$nombre_estado)
names(y)<-c(x)
barplot(y)
```

El problema es que tengo 32 barras, a cada barra le corresponde un nombre sin embargo sólo algunas barras muestran su nombre correspondiente.
Cómo podría mostrar todos los nombres de todas las barras?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes mostrar las etiquetas de forma vertical:

```
y<-(dtab$clave_estado)
x<-(dtab$nombre_estado)
names(y)<-c(x)
barplot(y, las=3)
```